# Workflow using Google Apps Script - I need to email the user in my first step

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, google-apps-script

I'm creating a workflow process that will email a body of a form to users in that workflow. I can iterate through the users and send an email but I do not now how to pass the "e" parameters for the body of the email. I actually already have a function that will send the body , but I need to include this in my step process (I think).

Hear is my code that will send email

```
function sendEmail_(e) {


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AuCblud0Ss7sdfA1bXZjYXA0Y0IhthkhUQm5vWG02MVE").getActiveSheet();


 var row = sheet.getLastRow()+1;

 sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(row);

    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,23);
 range.setValues([[e.parameter.LastName,e.parameter.FirstName,row /*e.parameter.DivisionName*/,e.parameter.EffectiveDate,e.parameter.Status, 

          e.parameter.Network,e.parameter.EmployeeNewPosition,e.parameter.DivisionFolder,e.parameter.SpecificIndividual,
                    e.parameter.Email,e.parameter.username,e.parameter.who,e.parameter.Banner,e.parameter.RMS ,e.parameter.HAPPY,e.parameter.Sweeps,
                   e.parameter.Comcate,e.parameter.Netviewer,e.parameter.NetDispatcher,e.parameter.IMARS,"pending", e.parameter.DivHeadEmail,  e.parameter.Director]]);


   var body = '<form action= <form action = " https://sites.google.com/a/macros/wichitafallstx.gov/s/AKfycbxAOGO6q9ofauf34xlDA9sLG8sUXeZsuvQkDKATOQ/exec" method ="post">' +

      "<b>Last Name:</b>" + e.parameter.LastName +  '<br><br>' + 
 "<b>First Name:</b>" +  e.parameter.FirstName +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Division Name:</b>" + e.parameter.DivisionName +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Effective Date:</b>" + e.parameter.EffectiveDate +  '<br><br>' + 
  "<b>Employee Status:</b>" + e.parameter.Status +  '<br><br>' + 
    "<b>Network:</b>" + e.parameter.Network +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Employee New Position:</b>" + e.parameter.EmployeeNewPosition +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Division Folder:</b>" + e.parameter.DivisionFolder +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Specific Individual:</b>" + e.parameter.SpecificIndividual +   '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Email:</b>" + e.parameter.Email +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Username:</b>" + e.parameter.username +  '<br><br>' +  
"<b>who:</b>" + e.parameter.who +  '<br><br>' + 
"<b>Banner:</b>" + e.parameter.Banner + '<br><br>' + 
"<b>RMS:</b>" + e.parameter.RMS + '<br><br>' + 
  "<b>HAPPY:</b>" + e.parameter.HAPPY + '<br><br>' + 
    "<b>Sweeps:</b>" + e.parameter.Sweeps + '<br><br>' + 
      "<b>Comcate:</b>" + e.parameter.Comcate + '<br><br>' + 
        "<b>Netviewer:</b>" + e.parameter.Netviewer + '<br><br>' + 
          "<b>NetDispatcher:</b>" + e.parameter.NetDispatcher + '<br><br>' + 
            "<b>IMARS:</b>" + e.parameter.IMARS + 
      '<br />' + 
       '<br />' +    

         '<input type="hidden" name="row" value=" ' + row +' "/>' +
       '<input type="submit" value="Approve" onclick="approve()" />' +
         '</form>' 
            ; 



  //  var owners = e.parameter.DivHeadEmail;
//  var mail = MailApp.sendEmail(owners, "test",'' , {htmlBody:body});


}
```

I need to email the html body from the code above with the step in the work flow in this "createStep" function. I dont know how to reference the variable "body" from the code above to this function or even if I could include the html body in this function. How would I do this?

```
function createStep(approvers) {





 var step = new Object();//javascript object

  step['numberOfApprovers'] = approvers.length; //set number of approvers passed in array
 step['approvers'] = approvers.slice(0); //slice copies array 
  step['status'] = 'pending'; //set statust to pedning

  for (var i in approvers)
    step[approvers[i]] = 'pending'; //iterate field that indicates specific status

for (var m in approvers)
    step[approvers[m]] = MailApp.sendEmail(approvers, "test", "test",{htmlBody:body});

  return step



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the body variable in both functions, declare the variable outside the functions:

```
var body;

function sendEmail_(e) {
  ...
  body = ...

}

function createStep(approvers) {
  ...
  sendEmail(..., {htmlBody:body}
  ..
}
```

However, I don't think you can send POST parameters to a script, GET should work. But I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, and trying to understand the process, why not create a web app that just displays the info on the screen, with an Approve button under it, and send a link to that app to each approver?
Advantage is that you can give access to the script to logged in users only, and check that the right person is approving--makes it more safe.

Note that you can use the ObjDB library to easily retrieve a row from a spreadsheet:
http://www.harryonline.net/scripts/objdb-storing-data-with-google-apps-script/482

Comment: How can I define the body outside of the function when it has "e" parameters? It returns an error that says "..Parameter is undefined". I need to to send my html form that contains the e parameter to all the approvers in my step. If you know of a better way by all means we work my code.

Comment: How can I display the info back to the screen? Open up the Json Feed? and how would I construct the flow of approvers?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a spreadsheet with two worksheets. The first contains the data, the second contains the list of approvers. One column in the first sheet indicates the last approver.

So your script checks the rows in the data worksheet, and sends an email containing the data of a row that has not been approved yet. It includes a link to approve. The receiver checks the data, and clicks on the link to approve.

This brings him to a script, where he has to log in. The script checks the user with the expected approver, and if OK, increases the value in the approver column in the data sheet. While there are more approvers, continue the loop.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. Do you have an example script I could follow?

Comment: No, I leave that to you :-)
But if you get stuck somewhere, post it here. 
There are two function in the script: one that checks for any unapproved rows, which you start manually or use a trigger. It sends the first email.
The other is a web app, which is called by an approver,  following the link in an email. It increases the counter and send an email to the next approver.